# Apache mod_rewrite works in .htaccess but not in apache conf file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

What I can do in .htaccess is take `example.com/s1/s2/s3` and have these as 3 elements in the `$_REQUEST` array in php.
How do I translate this to work correctly in the conf file?

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "/home/...path.../public"
        ServerName example.com
        Alias /lib /home/...path.../otherlib/
        <Directory />
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lib/ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lib/ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
> ```

When used in a *virtualhost* context, mod_rewrite is processed much earlier, before the request has been mapped to the filesystem. Consequently `REQUEST_FILENAME` does not yet contain the full filesystem path that the requested URL maps to, it contains just the root-relative URL (the same as `REQUEST_URI`). So, these two *negated* conditions will always be successful. (So all your static assets will be rewritten to the front-controller as well.)

You need to either, use a lookahead, eg. `%{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME}` or construct the filename from the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and `REQUEST_URI` server variables, which works in either context. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lib/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/. /index.php [L]
```

I also simplified the `RewriteRule` pattern, since there's no need to capture the URL-path here, or match the root directory. The `NC` and `QSA` flags are also unnecessary.

---

> What I can do in `.htaccess` is take `example.com/s1/s2/s3` and have these as 3 elements in the `$_REQUEST` array in php.

However, the above does not do this. With the above directives you can access the entire URL from the single `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal element in PHP, which you then need to parse/explode to extract `s1`, `s2` and `s3`.

If you specifically wanted 3 elements in the `$_REQUEST` array then you would need to change the `RewriteRule` directive to something like the following instead:

```
:
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?s1=$1&s2=$2&s3=$3 [L]
```

But that only matches URLs of the form `/foo/bar/baz`. A two-path-segment URL like `/foo/bar` would not be matched.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful and informative; solved my problem and has allowed me to tidy up and centralize this configuration.